# Can I trigger a Stored Proc in an Oracle Database Asynchronously?

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures

So I have an Oracle database that I connect to from my Python module using the CX_ORACLE package.
This works fine as long as I'm making synchronous calls but I was trying to figure out a way I can make this asynchronous as my stored proc on Oracle can take too much time and my connection to Oracle times out.

Is there a way that I can trigger my Stored Proc from my Python module and close the connection without terminating the instance of the Stored Proc triggered?

Answer (score 3):

In the way you are asking - no. When you disconnect, oracle kills your session (or at least tries to kill). But you can create a job. Job is an object managed by oracle instance. It has a schedule, which is used to run. Simplest example to create a job, which will run a stored procedure once:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name           =>  'My job',
      job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      job_action         =>  'YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_PROCEDURE',
      start_date         =>  'desired date to start',
      repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1', /* every day */
      end_date           =>  'desired date to stop',
      comments           =>  'I will run it from python');
end;
```

To run your procedure only once leave `start_date`, `repeat_interval` and `end_date` null:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name           =>  'My job',
      job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      job_action         =>  'YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_PROCEDURE',
      comments           =>  'I will run it from python');
end;
```

Oracle Scheduler is a very complex and powerful tool. Your can run procedure with parameters, anonymous blocks, create complex schedules, etc. To learn more, see the documentation: [Scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034), [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72260).

Comment: Thank you for your response @Dmitry. 
  However I also needed my Stored Proc to return a value to the Python code I was calling it from. I'm assuming its not possible in this case?

Comment: @SakshamArora Directly - no. But you can store the return value in a table.  Run the script, pass there an identifier (if you need to identify different procedure runs), then execute a procedure. Add to the procedure a code to save the result with the identifier, then make a select.